# O que significa _ no C#?

Tags: c#, característica-linguagem, sintaxe

Estava prestando manutenção em um sistema até que me deparei com o seguinte código:

```
object auth;
var authContext = HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue("SystemQueryContext", out auth);
var result = await _systemService.Metodo(auth as QueryContext);
```

Fiz a seguinte alteração:

```
var authContext = HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue("SystemQueryContext", out object auth);
var result = await _systemService.Metodo(auth as QueryContext);
```

Todavia, o *IntelliSense* do Visual Studio me ofereceu a seguinte mudança:

```
_ = HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue("SystemQueryContext", out object auth);
var result = await _systemService.Metodo(auth as QueryContext);
```

Eu nunca vi esse `_` sendo usado, tentei usá-lo como variável e não é possível, então gostaria de entender sobre esse recurso, em que casos pode-se usar, o que ele faz?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

É uma forma se indicar que não deseja usar valor algum. É como se fosse uma variável fictícia (mas não uma de verdade por isso não pode usá-la), então você está dizendo explicitamente que sabe que um valor está sendo recebido pelo método sendo chamado e que deseja que este valor seja descartado, por isso esta é uma construção de linguagem chamada [*discard*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que foi introduzida recentemente no C# 7.

De fato este método chamado faz parte de um dicionário e retorna um booleano conforme [documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). O retorno é se a operação deu certo ou não, portanto você deveria fazer algo em seguida condicionalmente, se deu errado o objeto obtido no `out` é inválido e não deveria ser usado, isso se não der erro de cara. Mesmo o Visual Studio indicando para fazer isso eu o usaria em um `if` e não usaria o *discard*, afinal o VS não viu o contexto todo, ele só entendeu que já que está criando uma variável e não a está usando, porque não descartar o valor e deixar de criar a variável inútil?

Obviamente que este mesmo símbolo pode usado em um nome de variável como um caractere qualquer (desde que o nome não seja só este caractere), mas não é isto que deseja saber, não é idiomático em C# usá-lo de qualquer forma, nunca foi, isto é vício de outras linguagens, `_systemService` não vai prejudicar em nada, mas toda vez que eu vejo parece que não é C#.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: A ideia era justamente chegar no `if` mas bati enter sem ler :D